# Qt authenticationRequired over HTTPS and downloading file

Tags: c++, qt, authentication, https

I've been trying to adapt a small Qt program designed to download a single file from a server. All it does (for now) is ask for a URL, then it downloads it.

What I'd want to do before going on more complex is to get it to work with authentication. After reading documentation and finding a few examples involving QNetworkAccessManager and QAuthenticator classes I tried modifying it. But for some reason, while I correctly link the authenticationRequired signal from my QNetworkAccessManager instance to a custom slot and set the username/ password to the QAuthenticator objet, it seems the authenticationRequired signal is never sent (putting a qDebug inside the slot did. Username and password are hard-coded for now (something I plan to add later when I get this to work).

I verified I did put the connect() before calling get() and tried several places for it : first thing I tried was placing the QNetworkAccessManager creation in my class' constructor, then just before using get(). But nothing seems to work, as all I get when trying a download requiring auth is a 'forbidden' error code. As I had never worked with Qt Network classes before, I'm not sure to spot where I did something wrong.

Here's my full code

```
//HttpDownload.h
#ifndef HTTPDOWNLOAD_H
#define HTTPDOWNLOAD_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QProgressDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDir>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAuthenticator>

namespace Ui {
class HttpDownload;
}

class HttpDownload : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit HttpDownload(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~HttpDownload();

public:
    void startRequest(QUrl url);
private slots:
    void on_downloadButton_clicked();

    void on_quitButton_clicked();

    void on_urlEdit_returnPressed();

    // slot for readyRead() signal
    void httpReadyRead();

    // slot for finished() signal from reply
    void httpDownloadFinished();

    // slot for downloadProgress()
    void updateDownloadProgress(qint64, qint64);

    void enableDownloadButton();
    void cancelDownload();
    void authRequired(QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator*); // Auth slot
private:
    Ui::HttpDownload *ui;
    QUrl url;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QProgressDialog *progressDialog;
    QFile *file;
    bool httpRequestAborted;
    qint64 fileSize;

};

#endif // HTTPDOWNLOAD_H

//HttpDownload.cpp
#include "httpdownload.h"
#include "ui_httpdownload.h"

HttpDownload::HttpDownload(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::HttpDownload)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->urlEdit->setText(HTTPS_URL);
    ui->statusLabel->setWordWrap(true);
    ui->downloadButton->setDefault(true);
    ui->quitButton->setAutoDefault(false);

    progressDialog = new QProgressDialog(this);

    connect(ui->urlEdit,
            SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
            this,
            SLOT(enableDownloadButton())
        );
    connect(progressDialog,
            SIGNAL(canceled()),
            this,
            SLOT(cancelDownload())
        );
}

HttpDownload::~HttpDownload()
{
    delete ui;
}

// Auth slot
void HttpDownload::authRequired(QNetworkReply *reply, QAuthenticator *ator)
{
    qDebug() << "auth Alert";
    qDebug() << reply->readAll(); // this is just to see what we received
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << ator->realm();
    ator->setUser(QString(USERNAME));
    ator->setPassword(QString(PASSWORD));
}

void HttpDownload::on_downloadButton_clicked()
{
//    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    // get url
    url = (ui->urlEdit->text());

    QFileInfo fileInfo(url.path());
    QString fileName = fileInfo.fileName();

    if (fileName.isEmpty())
        fileName = "index.html";

    if (QFile::exists(fileName)) {
        if (QMessageBox::question(this, tr("HTTP"),
                tr("There already exists a file called %1 in "
                "the current directory. Overwrite?").arg(fileName),
                QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No, QMessageBox::No)
                == QMessageBox::No)
                return;
        QFile::remove(fileName);
    }

    file = new QFile(fileName);
    if (!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("HTTP"),
                      tr("Unable to save the file %1: %2.")
                      .arg(fileName).arg(file->errorString()));
        delete file;
        file = 0;
        return;
    }

    // used for progressDialog
    // This will be set true when canceled from progress dialog
    httpRequestAborted = false;

    progressDialog->setWindowTitle(tr("HTTP"));
    progressDialog->setLabelText(tr("Downloading %1.").arg(fileName));

    // download button disabled after requesting download
    ui->downloadButton->setEnabled(false);

    startRequest(url);
}

void HttpDownload::httpReadyRead()
{
    // this slot gets called every time the QNetworkReply has new data.
    // We read all of its new data and write it into the file.
    // That way we use less RAM than when reading it at the finished()
    // signal of the QNetworkReply
    if (file)
        file->write(reply->readAll());
}

void HttpDownload::updateDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes)
{
    if (httpRequestAborted)
        return;

    progressDialog->setMaximum(totalBytes);
    progressDialog->setValue(bytesRead);
}

void HttpDownload::on_quitButton_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void HttpDownload::on_urlEdit_returnPressed()
{
    on_downloadButton_clicked();
}

void HttpDownload::enableDownloadButton()
{
    ui->downloadButton->setEnabled(!(ui->urlEdit->text()).isEmpty());
}

// During the download progress, it can be canceled
void HttpDownload::cancelDownload()
{
    ui->statusLabel->setText(tr("Download canceled."));
    httpRequestAborted = true;
    reply->abort();
    ui->downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
}

// When download finished or canceled, this will be called
void HttpDownload::httpDownloadFinished()
{
    // when canceled
    if (httpRequestAborted) {
        if (file) {
            file->close();
            file->remove();
            delete file;
            file = 0;
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
        progressDialog->hide();
        return;
    }

    // download finished normally
    progressDialog->hide();
    file->flush();
    file->close();

    // get redirection url
    QVariant redirectionTarget = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    if (reply->error()) {
        file->remove();
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("HTTP"),
                                 tr("Download failed: %1.")
                                 .arg(reply->errorString()));
        ui->downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
    } else if (!redirectionTarget.isNull()) {
        QUrl newUrl = url.resolved(redirectionTarget.toUrl());
        if (QMessageBox::question(this, tr("HTTP"),
                                  tr("Redirect to %1 ?").arg(newUrl.toString()),
                                  QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes) {
            url = newUrl;
            reply->deleteLater();
            file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            file->resize(0);
            startRequest(url);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        QString fileName = QFileInfo(QUrl(ui->urlEdit->text()).path()).fileName();
        ui->statusLabel->setText(tr("Downloaded %1 to %2.").arg(fileName).arg(QDir::currentPath()));
        ui->downloadButton->setEnabled(true);
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = 0;
    delete file;
    file = 0;
    manager = 0;
}

// This will be called when download button is clicked
void HttpDownload::startRequest(QUrl url)
{
    qDebug() << "Begin download";

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(manager,
        SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
        SLOT(authRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*))
        );

    // get() method posts a request
    // to obtain the contents of the target request
    // and returns a new QNetworkReply object
    // opened for reading which emits
    // the readyRead() signal whenever new data arrives.
    reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    // Whenever more data is received from the network,
    // this readyRead() signal is emitted
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(httpReadyRead()));

    // Also, downloadProgress() signal is emitted when data is received
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),
            this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

    // This signal is emitted when the reply has finished processing.
    // After this signal is emitted,
    // there will be no more updates to the reply's data or metadata.
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(httpDownloadFinished()));
}

//main.cpp
#include "httpdownload.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    HttpDownload w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Http Download");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Connects just wire up calls which will happen in the future. You should do all your connects before any calls which might trigger them. After that, if the auth event never occurs, it means the host is the issue, not your code. Your approach for auth looks correct. Try tracing it with Fiddler or something similar.

Comment: I suspected the host first, but since I've been able to download files (over HTTPS with basic auth from the same host) using PHP, so I guess it can't be it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'r missing a **this** just before SLOT!

```
connect(manager,
        SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
        SLOT(authRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*))
        );
```

should be

```
connect(manager,
            SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
            this, SLOT(authRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*))
            );
```

Comment: The presence of **this** (or its absence) have the same effect : authenticationRequired() signal is never sent.